# Intersection of independent events

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ be independent with each other events with$ P(A)=0.4 , P(B)=0.5 ,P(C)=0.6$ .How can I compute $P((A \cup B) \cap \overline{C})$

I found out that  $P((A \cup B) \cap \overline{C})$ = $P(A)- P(A\cap B) + P(B) - P(B \cap C) - [ P(A \cap B) -P(A\cap B \cap C)] 
=P(A)-P(A)P(B)+P(B)-P(B)P(C)-[P(A)P(B)-P(A)P(B)P(C)]$

Is my solution correct and is there a easier way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A,B,C$ are mutually independent then also $A\cup B$ and $\overline C$ are independent, leading to:$$P\left((A\cup B)\cap\overline C\right)=P(A\cup B)P(\overline C)$$

You can work further out by applying:

- $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)+P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)+P(A)P(B)$
- $P(\overline C)=1-P(C)$

Now check yourself.